# NodeJS JSON Axios Request - Memory Efficiency

Tags: node.js, performance, memory, axios

I am trying to find a more memory efficient way to make multiple JSON requests in nodejs. My application makes ~500-1000 calls, each returning approx 1mb of JSON data.

At present I am using Axios to make the request, and I'm pushing ~1000 requests into an array to pass to Axios.

eg.

```
 let axiosPromises = [];
 let baseURL = "http://someurl.example.com/?";
 let requests = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', ... 'page1000'];

 for (let j = 0; j < requests.length; j++) {        

   let axiosPromise = axios.get(baseURL + requests[j], {
            timeout: 300000
   });

   axiosPromises.push(axiosPromise);
 }



 axios.all(axiosPromises).then((response) => {
   // Code to place JSON responses into an array of objects
 }
```

As all of these requests combined are returning approx 900mb of JSON data, I'm seeing memory of node blow out to ~900mb. I'm wondering how this can be handled in a more scaleable / memory-efficient manner.

I have read about using streaming for memory efficiency when it comes to reading/writing large files etc in node. I'm wondering what the recommended approach would be to a situation like this, where many thousands of web requests are made and the responses are stored in an array of objects.

Many thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Queues are your friend here.

Comment: @RobertMoskal thanks for the response. Have you used this approach before? I'm wondering if you may have a code sample or a recommended queuing module that I can investigate. Thanks again

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/kue

Comment: On of the features of the queue is to break concurrent requests into sequential ones so they don't use up your memory. Or to move them out of process, so they don't affect your main app.

Comment: Thanks @RobertMoskal - I've done some testing with queuing and have determined this isn't helping to reduce the memory footprint. Whether I run with 1 concurrent request, or 100 concurrent requests, the same amount of memory is used (it just takes longer to accumulate when I limit the concurrency). I'm left thinking that the cause may be the size of the JSON responses, and that these are being stored in memory? Surely there must be a better way to handle this that I haven't considered, I'm relatively new to nodejs.

Comment: It could be the size of the JSON responses, just like you said. We've been stress testing our application with over 5000 requests and it does not blow out.

Comment: Will you share what you are doing with the responses when they are returned? If you are accumulating all the responses then the memory will be the same with or without a queue

Comment: Use Redis Data store

Comment: Ever considered having more than one thread in this case? You could make use of *libuv* / *Os* module to make use of cpu's that your server is running on  either in development or production and having more than one thread you can offload weight so to have things running faster...

Answer (score 0):

Write the response data to disk instead of holding it in memory

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const axios = require('axios');
const TMP_DIR = fs.mkdtempSync(__dirname + '/');

const makeRequest = async function(page) {
  const baseUrl = 'http://someurl.example.com/?'
  const resp = await axios.get(baseUrl + page);
  const file = path.join(TMP_DIR, page)

  return promisify(fs.writeFile)(file, resp.data);
}


const main = async function() {
  const pages = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3'];
  for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    await makeRequest(pages[i])
 }
}

main()
```